# Difference between LiveData, MutableLiveData

Tags: android, android-studio, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I know that the `MutableLiveData` extends `LiveData`, 
but what is the difference between them (in usage). What are appropriate use cases, means when to use the correct one from the two?

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814158/why-theres-a-separate-mutablelivedata-subclass-of-livedata

Comment: Use Live Data when you don't intend to modify it in the future otherwise Mutable Live Data

Answer (score 9):

`LiveData` is immutable while `MutableLiveData` is mutable. `MutableLiveData` extends `LiveData` and provides methods like `setValue()` and `postValue()`.

Comment: `LiveData` provides methods `setValue()` and `postValue()` too but they are protected, not public

Comment: Please why are they protected?

Comment: Because it is not mutable.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen Because they are available to the subclass (or creating classes like `MutableLiveData`) but are not part of the public interface.