# When to use MutableLiveData and LiveData

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

when to use `MutableLiveData` and `LiveData` means the area of using the methods :

```
MutableLiveData<User> getUser() {
    if (userMutableLiveData == null) {
        userMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return userMutableLiveData;
}
```

and when to use this,

```
LiveData<User> getUser() {
    if (userMutableLiveData == null) {
        userMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return userMutableLiveData
}
```

Comment: Basically, you expose it as `LiveData` to UI *(Activity/Fragment)* as it can't modify it directly and expose it to Repositories as `MutableLiveData` *(if using in project)*.

Comment: please make me understand by giving one simple example

Answer (score 71, accepted):

LiveData has no public method to modify its data.

```
LiveData<User> getUser() {
    if (userMutableLiveData == null) {
        userMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }
    return userMutableLiveData
}
```

You can't update its value like `getUser().setValue(userObject)` or `getUser().postValue(userObject)`

So when you don't want your data to be modified use `LiveData`
If you want to modify your data later use `MutableLiveData`

Comment: what you are saying we cant update live data values in wrong. LiveDate is not synchronised but Mutable live data in synchronised and also have ability to invoke observer from Worker thread using its postValue methods.

So when you don't want your data to be modified use LiveData If you want to modify your data later use MutableLiveData` this not right statement.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46814158/why-theres-a-separate-mutablelivedata-subclass-of-livedata

Comment: I quite didn't understand your comment, the link also iterates the same message. `LiveData` is an abstract class with protected `setValue` and `postValue` methods and is supposed to be used to restrict modifications in activity or fragments. Could you please provide an example where you can update a `LiveData` value with `setValue` or `postValue`?

Comment: But, can't you just cast the returned LiveData to MutableLiveData?

Comment: MVVM newbie here. I learnt that `LiveData` is [the sole way](https://android.jlelse.eu/mvvm-how-view-and-viewmodel-should-communicate-8a386ce1bb42) for `ViewModel` to communicate to `View`. What's the point of an immutable `LiveData` then?

Answer (score 24):

Let's say you're following **MVVM architecture** and having `LiveData` as observable pattern from `ViewModel` to your `Activity`. So that you can make your variable as `LiveData` object exposing to `Activity` like below :

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // LiveData object as following
    var someLiveData: LiveData<Any> = MutableLiveData()

    fun changeItsValue(someValue: Any) {
        (someLiveData as? MutableLiveData)?.value = someValue
    }
}
```

And now at `Activity` part, you can observe `LiveData` but for modification you can call method from `ViewModel` like below :

```
class SomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Inside onCreateMethod of activity
    val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this)[MyViewModel::class.java]
    viewModel.someLiveData.observe(this, Observer{
        // Here we observe livedata
    })
    viewModel.changeItsValue(someValue) // We call it to change value to LiveData
    // End of onCreate
}
```

Comment: @c0ming Another way to achieve this by creating two objects in ViewModel. `MutableLiveData` object can be private & manipulated by setter method while public object can be `LiveData` reassigned from above private object.

Comment: @JeelVankhede You're right my friend, this is the recommended way on the official Udacity couse made by Google developers. It's the way to encapsulate the information we don't want our classes to edit. Check out the course at: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud9012

Answer (score 16):

`LiveData` has no public available methods to update the stored data. The `MutableLiveData` class exposes the `setValue(T)` and `postValue(T)` methods public and you must use these if you need to edit the value stored in a `LiveData` object. Usually `MutableLiveData` is used in the `ViewModel` and then the `ViewModel` only exposes immutable `LiveData` objects to the observers.
Please take a look at this [reference](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#update_livedata_objects).

Answer (score 15):

We should return LiveData in order to prevent views (or other observers) from accident value modification.

Having:

```
    LiveData<User> getUser() {
       if (userMutableLiveData == null) {
           userMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
       }
       return userMutableLiveData
    }
```

you can't write in your activity / fragment: `getUser().setValue(...)`. This makes your code less bug prone.

Answer (score 1):

Best Approach of using MutableLiveData  in seprate class
Like

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
private MutableLiveData<CharSequence>text = new MutableLiveData<>();

public void setText(CharSequence input)
{
    text.setValue(input);
}

public LiveData<CharSequence> getText(){
    return text;

}
}
```

Livedata is Used  in Fragment Like

```
private SharedViewModel viewModel;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        //No Need to initate further
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
                editText.setText(charSequence);
            }
        });
    }
```

in Fragment Class be Like

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment {
    private SharedViewModel viewModel;
    private EditText editText;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        editText = v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
        Button button = v.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewModel.setText(editText.getText());
            }
        });
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
                editText.setText(charSequence);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between LiveData and MutableLiveData is:

- you can change the value of MutableLiveData but LiveData does
  not allow you to change it's value
- LiveData only allows you to observe its value.

They are usually used together. so MutableLiveData is used to record the changed value and LiveData is used to notify the UI about the change value.

Answer (score 0):

Use **LiveData** when you don't want to modify it because the methods like **setValue()** & **postValue()** are not public .Live data takes care itself by calling them internally.

Where as in MutableLiveData **setValue()** **postValue()** are exposed ie public.You can change set values by calling these methods.

Find more details here :
https://blog.mindorks.com/livedata-setvalue-vs-postvalue-in-android

Answer (score 0):

For best practice, readability and avoid error prone by mistake just like `MutableList` vs `List` in Kotlin. Use Mutable is when you want its data to be modified or you want to re assign a new value on it.

We use `MutableLiveData` when we want to make its value writable or can be change anytime.

We use `LiveData` when we just want to read and listen to any updates made by `MutableLiveData`. Thus we have this kind of code as sample

```
private var filterAsset = MutableLiveData<String>().apply{
        value = "Empty"
    }

    //public method to set a new value on filterAsset
    fun setFilterData(assetName: String){
        filterAsset.value = assetName
    }

// We can use this to listen on any updates from filterAsset
val assetFilterUpdates: LiveData<String> = filterAsset


// Inside your Fragment/Activity
// You can listen to the update in Fragment or Activity like this 
yourViewModel.assetFilterUpdates.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { value ->

            // Use the updated value here

        })
```