# How to use the keyword also in kotlin android

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

Am learning android kotlin follow this:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#kotlin

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val users: MutableLiveData<List<User>> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<List<User>>().also {
        loadUsers(it)
    }
}

fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<User>> {
    return users
}

private fun loadUsers() {
    // Do an asynchronous operation to fetch users.
}
}
```

Dont know how to write the fun loadUsers()

Here is my User:

```
class User  {

 constructor(name: String?) {
      this.name = name
 }

 var name:String? = null
 }
```

If dont use the keyword 'also' , i know how to do it.
But if use 'also' , it seems not work.

Here is how i try to write the  fun loadUsers:

```
private fun loadUsers( it: MutableLiveData<List<User>>){
    val users: MutableList<User> = ArrayList()
    for (i in 0..9) {
        users.add(User("name$i"))
    }
    it =  MutableLiveData<List<User>>(users)
}
```

Error tips near it : Val cant be ressigned

Comment: what do you ask exactly?can you be more clear.Are you asking about how to fetch users or what?

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1:** According to [the Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/also.html), `also` provides the object in question to the function block as a `this` parameter. So, every function call and property object you access is implied to refer to your `MutableLiveData<List<User>>()` object. `also` returns `this` from the function block when you are done.

Thus, another way of writing your `MutableLiveData<>` would be like this:

```
val users = MutableLiveData<List<User>>()
users.loadUsers()
```

**Part 2:** As far as how to implement `loadUsers()`, that is a separate issue (your question is not clear). You can use Retrofit + RxJava to load the data asynchronously, and that operation is totally outside of the realm of `ViewModel` or `also`.

**Part 3:** With your approach, you have conflicting things going on. Instead of doing a `loadUsers()` from your `lazy {}` operation, I would remove your `lazy {}` operation and create a `MutableLiveData<>` directly. Then, you can load users later on and update the `users` property any time new data is loaded. [Here is a similar example](https://gitlab.com/oliverspryn/multimodal-android-app/-/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/com/oliverspryn/android/multimodal/ui/adaptivelayouts/AdaptiveLayoutsViewModel.kt) I worked on a while ago. It uses state flows, but the idea is similar. Also use a `data class` to model the `User` instead of a regular `class`. [Another example.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55915021/)

Answer (score 0):

It is solved change to code:

```
private fun loadUsers( it: MutableLiveData<List<User>>){
    val users: MutableList<User> = ArrayList()
    for (i in 0..9) {
        users.add(User("name$i"))
    }
    it.value =  users
}
```

it can't be reassigned , but it.value could .