# How to check changing collection?

Tags: android, kotlin, collections, observablelist

Depending on the number of items in the collection, I want to do certain actions.

For example

```
if i have 1 item in collection -> doFirstAction()
if i have 2 or more items in collection -> doSecondAction()
if i have 2 or more items in collection and deleted all instead one -> doSecondAction()
```

On this basis i need to check changing the list.

I found something similar: [ObservableList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList). And it seems to solve my problem, but unfortunately I do not know how it can be used correctly.

In my class i need check this collection:

```
var viewModels: List<ConnectionViewModel> = emptyList()
```

**UPDATE**:
With this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58979280/6387618) i write smth like this:

```
var viewModels: ObservableList<ConnectionViewModel> = ObservableArrayList<ConnectionViewModel>()
```

And add listener on my collection:

```
fun setOnDataChange() {
    viewModels.addOnListChangedCallback(object :
        ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback<ObservableList<ConnectionViewModel>>() {
        override fun onChanged(sender: ObservableList<ConnectionViewModel>?) {}

        override fun onItemRangeRemoved(
            sender: ObservableList<ConnectionViewModel>?,
            positionStart: Int,
            itemCount: Int
        ) {
            showBiometricConfirmation = showConfirmation(itemCount)
        }

        override fun onItemRangeMoved(
            sender: ObservableList<ConnectionViewModel>?,
            fromPosition: Int,
            toPosition: Int,
            itemCount: Int
        ) {}

        override fun onItemRangeInserted(
            sender: ObservableList<ConnectionViewModel>?,
            positionStart: Int,
            itemCount: Int
        ) {
            showBiometricConfirmation = showConfirmation(itemCount)
        }

        override fun onItemRangeChanged(
            sender: ObservableList<ConnectionViewModel>?,
            positionStart: Int,
            itemCount: Int
        ) {}
    })
}

private fun showConfirmation(itemCount: Int): Boolean {
    return itemCount != 1
}
```

But i have some problem
I need check the number in the collection. If number was 3 and after i delete 2, i also need to call `doSecondAction()`. but if collection number was 1, need to call `doFirstAction()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Resolve my problem with next solution:

Create next var:

```
private var quickConfirmMode: Boolean = false
```

And use it in my custom setter:

```
var viewModels: List<ConnectionViewModel> = emptyList()
    set(value) {
        quickConfirmMode = value.size == 1 && (field.size == 1 || field.isEmpty())
        field = value
    }
```

Solution:
Where field is backing property, which save my value. More information about getters and setters you can read [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html).
So in my custom setter i check my new and old value, then I set the value for `quickConfirmMode`.

Answer (score 3):

First you should enable dataBinding in gradle, inside android{}

```
android {
    ......
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}
```

Then, in your code create empty list:

```
   val list: ObservableList<String> = ObservableArrayList<String>()
```

You can set listener like this:

```
list.addOnListChangedCallback(object:ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback<ObservableList<String>>(){
            override fun onChanged(sender: ObservableList<String>?) {
                Log.d("Misha", "changed")
            }

            override fun onItemRangeRemoved(sender: ObservableList<String>?, positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                ...
            }

            override fun onItemRangeMoved(sender: ObservableList<String>?, fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                ...
            }

            override fun onItemRangeInserted(sender: ObservableList<String>?, positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                ...
            }

            override fun onItemRangeChanged(sender: ObservableList<String>?, positionStart: Int, itemCount: Int) {
                ...
            }    
 })
```

You can add(remove) values like this, or with other methods:

```
 list.addAll(0, listOf("Misha", "Akopov"))
```

Comment: in my case i need change `var viewModels: List<ConnectionViewModel> = emptyList()` on `var viewModels: ObservableList<ConnectionViewModel> = ObservableArrayList<ConnectionViewModel>()` ?

And after this whole my logic with size of collection i need to insert in `onChanged`?

Comment: Yes, you will have listener on that list

Comment: sorry but i don't understan how i can see that my collection was changed?
For example as it is possible to write down a condition that a pier 
the size of the collection was three and became one for example?

Comment: Please read this one, parametr descriptions https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableList.OnListChangedCallback#onitemrangechanged

Comment: This is about update content in collection.
But I need to react to changes in the number of items in the collection itself

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) + Observer pattern.

1. ViewModel. We put the list that will be observed here

```
// SETTER
val _myList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>()

// GETTER
val myList: LiveData<MutableList<Item>> = _myList

init {

   _myList.value.add(item1)
   ... add remaining items

}
```

2. Activity. We modify / set the list and observe the list changes.

```
mViewModel.myList.observe(this, Observer{

   // it == myList
   if (it.size == 1) doFirstAction()
   else if (it.size >= 2) doSecondAction()
   else if (it.size >= 2 && deleted all instead one) do second action

})

// MODIFY LIST
mViewModel._myList.value.remove(item2)
mViewModel._myList.value.add(item4)
```

There will be a lot of null check warning. And later on you might wanna make `_myList` private and do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168990/8193483)